# Proof of Paralellogram

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the figure, if $P$, $Q$, $R$ and $S$ are respectively midpoints of $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ and $DA$ of parallelogram $ABCD$, prove that $\mathrm{ar}(PQRS)=\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{ar}(ABCD)$

Note : this is high-school homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Draw $PR$ and $SQ$ and name their intersection $O$. Can you see any similar triangles?

Good luck ;-)

Comment: Not $PSQ$ or $PQR$. Try looking for some more similar triangles.

Comment: Either of them would be fine, let it be $\triangle POQ$. Find _two_ triangles similar to it.